# date format is not implementing correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
self.storeArray = [dataDict valueForKey:@"list"];
for (int i=0; i<self.storeDict.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary * dateDic1=[self.storeArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"dict11 %@",dateDic1);
    NSString* dateStr = [dateDic1 objectForKey:@"dt"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([dateStr longLongValue] / 1000)];
    NSDateFormatter *datfrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [datfrm setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [datfrm stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"date-joined - %@",strDate);
    self.dateArry addObject:strDate];
}
```

1. output is date-joined - 18/01/1970

response is list

```
( { clouds = 0; 
    deg = 91; 
    dt = 1479967200; 
    humidity = 34; 
    pressure = "960.53"; 
    speed = "1.51"; 
    temp = { day = "35.2"; eve = "27.14"; max = "35.2"; min = "11.39"; morn = "28.91"; night = "11.39"; }; 
    weather = ( { description = "clear sky"; icon = 01d; id = 800; main = Clear; } );},

    { clouds = 0; 
      deg = 102; 
      dt = 1480053600; 
      humidity = 33; 
      pressure = "960.16"; 
      speed = "1.46"; 
      temp = { day = "29.01"; eve = "24.46"; max = "30.71"; min = "9.15"; morn = "9.15"; night = "11.83";};
    weather = ( { description = "clear sky"; icon = 01d; id = 800;
    main = Clear; } ); }, 

    { clouds = 0; 
      deg = 120; 
      dt = 1480140000;
      humidity = 37; 
      pressure = "960.83"; 
      speed = "1.62"; 
      temp = { day = "28.51"; eve = "24.42"; max = "30.33"; min = "10.66"; morn = "10.66";    night = "11.98"; }; 
      weather = ( { description = "clear sky"; icon = 01d; id = 800; main = Clear; } ); }, 

      { clouds = 0; 
        deg = 65; 
        dt = 1480226400; 
        humidity = 0; 
        pressure = "987.92";
        speed = "1.27"; 
        temp = { day = "28.7"; eve = "25.25"; max = "28.7"; min = "12.85"; morn = "12.85"; night = "15.51"; }; 
        weather = ( { description =    "clear sky"; icon = 01d; id = 800; main = Clear; } ); }, 
      { clouds = 0; 
        deg = 104; 
        dt = 1480312800;
        humidity = 0; 
        pressure = "987.88"; 
        speed = "1.39"; 
        temp = { day = "29.56"; eve = "26.25"; max = "29.56"; min = "13.13"; morn = "13.13"; night = "16.16"; }; 
        weather = ( { description = "light rain"; icon = 10d; id = 500; main = Rain; } ); }    )
```

Comment: properly format your question. It's not clear

Comment: I am trying but it always giving warning like please add some more code ... when i am changing code above formate it accepted

Comment: @P.VenkataVamsi There is no need to divide your value with `1000`. because you are not getting it in miliseconds. so simply convert your string to double and use it with `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970`.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your code to get the result:

```
NSString* dateStr = @"1479967200";
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([dateStr doubleValue])];
NSDateFormatter *datfrm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
datfrm.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[datfrm setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [datfrm stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"date-joined - %@",strDate);
```

Output:

> date-joined - 24/11/2016

Your issue is in while converting datestr to date i.e divided by 1000. Don't do that. Just change it and you will get your required result

Comment: Thank you buddy its working but in log it printing dd/mm/yyyy but in tableview its printing only dd 24 thats it my code is i am addind string in array its done good but in table view only date coming                                              NSNumber *dateNum = self.dateArry[indexPath.row];
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date  %ld",(long)dateNum.floatValue];

Comment: in my tableview cell the label i declared like this  self.dateLbl.text=dateLblStr;
    NSLog(@"dat label is %@",self.dateLbl.text);
here its printing only date how to change to print dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: oh..the self.dateArry already have the date string. So change it NSString *dateStr = self.dateArry[indexPath.row]; no need to format. then self.dateLbl.text = dateStr;

Comment: @ Sailendra Kumar how to call date formatter  method for multiple times  that means i am getting dates from jsondata i need the method declaration and passing data to that method and getting from that i am tried but not getting